# Send a windows form control to front and back on a form

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

Is it possible in vs2010 c#
To create a picture box and a textbox  on a form
where on the same form are some buttons too

And then by code put the picture and textbox as the most frontal element and later by code to put them as the most back background visual elements so be able to switch between front and back elements ?

During design time one can do this, but i don't see a property for it that could be changed
Or am i just overlooking it ?

Comment: Im confused, you tagged this `WPF` but are speaking about `form`s and `PictureBox`es, which are winforms concepts. Are you working with WPF or winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Textbox.sendtoback();
     Textbox.bringtofront();
```

Comment: This answer is misleading to others as WPF controls do NOT have `SendToBack` and `BringToFront` methods.

Comment: sa_ddam213 you where right i asked the wrong question in the past, it wasnt for a wpf but for a winform, i was just a bit confused about that when i asked it. I eddited the title so others might find this answer usefull

Answer (score 2):

That's where Z-Index comes in for you Z Axis. Read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex(v=vs.95).aspx

Take a `Canvas` and put inside whatever you want and then change Z-Index however you want. Here is an example:

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Canvas.ZIndex="3" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Fill="Silver" Width="10" Height="10" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I think thats silverlight specific (as written at the bottem of that hyperlink)

Comment: i dont undertand where there is code in here lik PictureBox.Zindex=2;

Comment: Show us your code and we will help you out. Here is an very very small example. Hehe

  <Canvas>
        <Ellipse 
    Canvas.ZIndex="3"
    Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Fill="Silver" />
</Canvas>

Do you know what a Canvas or Grid is? You can use ZIndex with Grid as well.

Comment: it the main form a canvas ? (i dont think so.. but its getting to late for me to test now should go to bed now)

Comment: Yea go to bed. Read more about WPF. Its nothing like WinForms.. There are no PictureBox in WPF. WPF is way cooler...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done, but it depends on what `Layout` control the `Controls` is inside

For example on `Grid` etc, you can use `Panel.ZIndex`

```
    <Grid>
        <Button Panel.ZIndex="1" />
        <Button Panel.ZIndex="0" />
    </Grid>
```

These are `AttachedProperties` that are inherated from the parent container

Comment: your using silverlight i think.. i am using a wpf form